# Button Click issue in Android Webview 4.4.2

Tags: android

I am running a web app in webview on android version 4.4.2. However the file upload button (in webview) seems to have frozen and nothing happens when i click on it.

Will be thankful if someone can provide any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your webview can't read javascript, try to add this to your webview :

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Comment: i tried this code but it still not working .Please help.

Comment: could you please add in your question your webview and everything you add to it ?